# Decode HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc5 for send JSON file from controler to view with viewmodel.

A part of text in my JSON file is:

```
"template": "{\"true\" : \"صحیح\", \"false\": \"غلط\" }"
```

When I send it to view it is automatically encoded and I use this function to decode it:

```
 function htmlDecode(input) {
            var e = document.createElement('div');
            e.innerHTML = input;
            return  e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        }
```

But the result is:

```
"template": "{"true" : "صحیح", "false": "غلط" }"
```

And I deal with an Error.

What should I do?

Comment: sounds like `input` is a string containing your json. Not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but you probably want to parse your json into an object `var obj = JSON.parse(input);`. Once you've done that, you can access your properties, maybe something like `e.innerHTML = obj.true`.

Comment: Also appears to be a problem with your JSON...there shouldn't be quotes outside of the curly braces. should be more like this: `"template": {"true":...}`

Comment: thanks @David784 for your answer, you right .
but in this case i have to use "template": "{"true":...}"